# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'session_start' (T_STRING)

Tags: php

Esto es lo que dice en el error la línea 12 esta en en php en el start session.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'session_start' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\paginas web\dulces\index.php on line 12

ya estuve buscando que podría ser pero no lo encuentro

```
    <?php include("menu.php")
        session_start();
        $counter_name = "counter.txt";
        if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
            $f = fopen($counter_name, "a");
            fwrite($f, "0");
            fclose($f);
        }
        $f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
        $counterval = fread($f,filesize($counter_name));
        fclose($f);
        if (!isset($_SESSION['hasvisited'])) {
            $_SESSION['hasvisited']="yes";
            $counterval++;
            $f =fopen($counter_name,"a");
            fwrite($f,$counterval);
            fclose($f);
        }
        echo '<font style="font-family:Comic Sans MS;color:white;font-size:40px;">eres el visitante $counterval en esta pagina</font>';
  ?>
```

Comment: intenta colocando primero "session_start();" luego el " include("menu.php");".. note olvides el *PUNTO Y COMA* al final del include

Comment: A tu include la hace falta un punto y coma

Comment: `<?php include("menu.php");` con punto y coma al final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a cerrar el include("menu.php") con punto y coma ;

Comment: gracias se ha solucionado

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas donde es un error tipográfico, no se deben responder y tal vez solo dejar un comentario

Answer (score -1):

hola al parecer todo está bien, pero previamente debes haber declarado tu variable algo así:
$_SESSION["hasvisited"]="Japón"

Para luego poder usarla así:
if (!isset($_SESSION['hasvisited'])) {